# Tensorflow: Why is my loss declining although my gradients are zero?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

For debugging of my code and understanding of RNNs I set my gradients manually to 0 like this:

```
gvs = optimizer.compute_gradients(cost)
gvs[0] = (tf.zeros((5002,2), dtype=tf.float32), tf.trainable_variables()[0])
gvs[1] = (tf.zeros((2,), dtype=tf.float32), tf.trainable_variables()[1])
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(gvs)
```

I only have two trainable variables, so above quick-and-dirty approach should set all gradients to zero:

```
tf.trainable_variables()
Out[8]: 
[<tf.Variable 'rnn/basic_rnn_cell/kernel:0' shape=(5002, 2) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'rnn/basic_rnn_cell/bias:0' shape=(2,) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

When I run the network the loss is still declining. How can that be? As far as I understand the new variable values should be old value + learning rate * gradients.

I am using the AdaGradOptimizer.

**Update**: `np.sum(sess.run(gvs[0][0]))` and `np.sum(sess.run(gvs[1][0]))` both return 0.

Comment: You should probably check that gvs indeed contains only 0s after you modify it... And is there anything that changes in your networks besides the trainable variables ? For instance if you have batch normalization, its computed mean and variance may change over time without being really trainable (I don't think they show up in tf.trainable_variables(), I may be wrong about this; but this or similar things could happen).

Comment: I checked gvs both return only 0s. I don't use batch normalization. What other things could you think of that do not show up in `tf.trainable_variables()`?